# A simple proof of the fundamental theorem of Galois theory

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory, fields, alternative-proof

*Update.* It's now on the [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.07508).

---

Some time ago I found my "own" proof of the [fundamental theorem of Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory). You can find a pdf with the proof (link removed, see arXiv). It is quite short, self-contained, and uses a neat combinatorial argument:

> A field cannot be written as a union of finitely many proper subfields

Most users of mathoverflow can simply skip most of it and only read the combinatorial Lemma 3.3. which leads to Prop. 4.2, as well as Lemma 5.5 which leads to to Prop. 6.3. The rest is easy.

I wonder if this proof is new or not. For sure I have never seen it before, and I checked a bit the literature and couldn't find it so far. But also I am not really an expert on the history of algebra at all, and my days as an "active mathematician" are over anyway. Hopefully somebody else has a better overview?

Comment: +1. Let me mention the link https://math.stackexchange.com/a/89576/660 even if it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I 've definitely seem that a vector space cannot be written as a finite union of proper subspaces to prove prove the primitive element theorem

Comment: For the history part, it’s worth noting that the fundamental theorem of Galois theory wasn’t proved (or stated) until a century after Galois died, by Artin. Galois himself did not find a correspondence between subgroups of automorphism groups and intermediate fields.

Comment: I agree with @BenjaminSteinberg. That said, although I cannot comment on novelty, your proof of Prop. 4.2 is very neat, and substantially easier than the one I know. It reminds me of how Galois theory for symmetric polynomials is proven (i.e. showing that $K(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n) \to K(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is Galois with group $S_n$), maybe in that it takes the extension field $L$ as the starting point instead of the base field $K = L^G$.

Comment: One small thing that I'm missing is equivalence with the other definition of Galois extension: a finite extension $K \to L$ is *Galois* if there exists a finite subgroup $G \subseteq \operatorname{Aut}(L)$ such that $K = L^G$. (This is not the right definition in the infinite case, for instance $K(T)$ has an automorphism $\sigma \colon T \mapsto T+1$ with $K(T)^{\sigma} = K$ if $K$ is infinite, but of course $K \to K(T)$ is not Galois. Can you fix this by asking for a profinite subgroup $G \subseteq \operatorname{Aut}(L)$ somehow?)

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg This is interesting, can you reference a proof along these lines? Also, what is the connection to the proof of the fundamental theorem? I guess that this offers an alternative way to finish the proof of Prop. 4.2 in the special case of finite separable extensions?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Thank you. Yes a lot of Galois theory is missing there, but the aim of the note is to prove the Galois correspondence, not (much) more. But maybe I will add this equivalent def' in the future.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard Thanks! I also found your *very short* proof of the fundamental theorem. https://vixra.org/abs/1207.0051. But it uses a very specific setup, so probably doesn't apply here(?).

Comment: In Prop 4.2 you have L is separable over L^H since each element satisfies the separable polynomial where you take the product over all distinct images of the element over H

Comment: I first saw it used for the primitive element in Algebre Theories Galoisiennes by Douady

Comment: The "neat combinatorial argument" is in Bourbaki, algebre, ch. V.40 (the section on the primitive element).

Comment: About Lemma 3.2: it's contained in a result of B.H. Neumann (Groups covered by finitely many cosets. 
Publ. Math. Debrecen 3 (1954), 227-242) which says that if a group is covered by finitely many cosets, it's covered by just those of finite index. In particular if the cover is not redundant, then all have finite index. So, if a group is covered in a non-redundant way by finitely many subgroups $G_i$, then the intersection $\bigcap G_i$ has finite index.

Comment: That your *days as an active mathematician* are over probably means that you continue your career outside academia. Good luck, Martin! I hope you are staying active in mathematics and, in particular, on MO.

Comment: @YCor Thanks for the reference. Actually all three lemmas in this section appear in the paper by Bialynicki-Birula, Browkin, Schinzel which I cite. I just repeated the proofs for the convenience of the reader.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Thank you for your kind words! Actually I've been out of academia since 2014. And the math game is an on/off since then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At a first glance your approach reminds me of [Meinolf Geck's](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.121.07.637#metadata_info_tab_contents) American Mathematical Monthly article, see also the [arxiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.3853) of his article.

Comment: This is a very interesting paper, thank you!

Comment: That is the paper I was going to mention too.

Comment: I have now mentioned this paper in the current  version of the pdf.

Comment: Although this is not a direct answer to my question, it is as close as it can get, I guess. The reaction here (and my further research) seems to indicate that there are proofs related to mine, but not the same. So I will accept it. Thank you!